# Redirect to a subdirectory using htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am using ProXCore in my website http://www.enkaizen.es/. I am trying to install wordpress on a subdirectory called "/soporte/"
The script came out of the box with an .htaccess like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

It does not allow to visit http://www.enkaizen.es/soporte/, it stays on the home page.
I added a rewrite line to the top so now the .htaccess file is like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on   
   RewriteRule    ^soporte/?$    soporte/   [L]
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But it is not working. If I take out the second and third rewrite lines it does work, meaning I can visit http://www.enkaizen.es/soporte/, but then the script itself, ProXCore script, does not work at all, and I really need to have a wordpress installation on the "/soporte/" directory.

Any ideas? Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For if someone facing this issue, I accomplished it by adding this rewrite line:

```
RewriteRule ^soporte/ - [L]
```

So the final htaccess file now is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
   RewriteRule ^soporte/ - [L]
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now it is working like a charm :D